# Save shape key animations as multiple actions and animations?

Tags: animation, unity

I've animated a costume mask with different expressions using shape keys. I have them all saved in blender in the shape key editor, and have pressed the F for fake user after each animation. I have been trying to make an action out of each one to export to unity, but I can't seem to get it to work.

What happens is I'll have one animation saved as "happy" with several key frames, open the action editor and insert the frames into the action and save it with F. I then create a new action and do the same with the "sad" animation and save with F, but if I go back to my saved "happy" action it now plays the same as the sad one in the action editor. When exporting to unity, all the animations play the same as the last one I made in the action editor.

I have looked at so many tutorials and can't find anything that will work for me. This is for my Graded Unit for college. I need it done soon and I'm tearing my hair out. My tutors who teach 3D modelling know so little about 3D modelling it's laughable so I have no one to help.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or am I doing something totally wrong?